Convergence of the Cesàro mean of iterated continuous functions
Does anyone have a counter-example of the following statement :
Let $f : [0;1] \to [0;1]$ a continuous function w.r.t. the usual topology. Let $A_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f^k(x)$ for $n \ge 1$, $x \in [0;1]$. Then $\forall x \in [0;1]$, $A_n(x)$ converges.

Represent Cantor space as ternary expansions without 1, and shift the expansion left there. Extend linearly to the gaps.

@VilleSalo Are you saying $f(x) = {3x}$ when $x$ has no $1$s in its ternary expansion?

@MonsieurBec: No, division by 3 has converging orbits, thus converging Cesàro means.

@mathworker21: yes

Let $f(x)$ be the continuous piecewise linear function with endpoints $(0,0)$, $(1/3,1)$, $(2/3,0)$, and $(1,1)$.  Define $I_0 = [0,1/3]$, $I_1 = [1/3, 2/3]$, and $I_2 = [2/3,1]$.  Note that $f$ is conjugate to the full shift map on $\{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{N}$.
Lemma: Let $A = \{x_0, x_1, x_2, ... x_{n-1}\}$ be a set of points in $I_0 \cup I_2$.  If the proportion of points in $A$ that are in $I_0$ is at least $9/10$, then the average value of the elements in $A$ is at most $2/5$.
Proof: Let $p$ be the proportion of elements of $A$ that are in $I_0$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i &\leq \frac{1}{3}p + 1(1-p) \\
&\leq 1 - \frac{2}{3}p \\
&\leq 1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \left(\frac{9}{10}\right) \\
&= \frac{2}{5}.
\end{align*}
A similar technique shows that if the proportion of points in $A$ that are in $I_2$ is at least $9/10$, then the average of those elements must be at least $3/5$.
Now, to show the existence of some $x$ whose Cesaro means do not converge, let $x$ be the point whose itinerary is given by
$$0\underbrace{(2...2)}_{9} \underbrace{(0...0)}_{90} \underbrace{(2...2)}_{900} \underbrace{(0...0)}_{9000}
\underbrace{(2...2)}_{90000} \underbrace{(0...0)}_{900000} ...$$
(The parentheses here are only for clarity.)  Then after $10^n$ iterates with $n \geq 2$, then at least $9/10$ iterates of $x$ have been in $I_0$ if $n$ is even, or in $I_2$ if $n$ is odd.  Then $A_n(x)$ is greater than $3/5$ and less than $2/5$ infinitely often, and therefore cannot converge.

I don't understand why f is conjugate to the full shift map on ${0,1,2}^{\mathbb{N}}$ because for example it seems to me that the shift of $x = 1,0,0 \ldots$ is 0 and that $x$ is associated to $1/3$ and that $f(1/3) = 1$.

What does "conjugate" mean here? The maps are not topologically conjugacy in the usual (?) sense because the spaces are not homeomorphic.

Anyway this is the same as my example from the comment.

Let $C \subset [0,1]$ be any Cantor space. Pick a homeomorphism $\pi : X \to C$ where $X = \{0,1\}^\omega$ has the product topology, and consider $g : C \to C$ corresponding to the left shift map, so $g(\pi(x_0x_1x_2\ldots)) = \pi(x_1x_2x_3\ldots)$. Take any continuous extension $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$, e.g. piecewise linear in the gaps.
Now let $x = 0^{1!} 1^{2!} 0^{3!} 1^{4!} 0^{5!} \ldots \in X$. Since $n!/\sum_{i < n} i! \rightarrow \infty$, we see that $\pi(x)$ has both $\pi(0^\omega)$ and $\pi(1^\omega)$ as Cesàro limit points under iteration of $g$, thus also under iteration of $f$. (You can pick a faster growing sequence than $n!$ to slightly simplify the proof.)

I'm sorry but I don't understand why your function f is continuous. For example, if I take $x = 1, 0, 0, \ldots \in X$ and for $n \ge 1$, I take : $e_n = 0,\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}{\text{n}},0,0 \ldots$ then $\lim{n \to \infty} \pi(e_n) = \pi(x)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(e_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(\pi(e_n)) = 1$ but $f(x) = g(\pi(x)) =0$.

No, $\pi(e_n)$ does not converge to $\pi(x)$, since clearly $e_n$ has the wrong initial digit and $\pi$ is a homeomorphism. Perhaps you think $X$ is about binary expansions, but it's not. Ternary expansions are one concrete realization.

Maybe I didn't understand X yeah but can you show me a concrete realization ? For me it was with the ternary expansions : $\pi(x_0,x_1,x_2 \ldots) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{2 x_k}{3^k}$ where $\forall k, x_k \in {0,1}$. Thus I did have $(\pi(e_n))_{n \ge 0})$ converges to $\pi(x)$. However I certainely didn't understand what you were actually saying so can you show me a concrete realization pls ?

My initial comment was a concrete example, and the other answer gives the resulting explicit formula. This one explains the same idea abstractly. You are wrong about that convergence with ternary expansions.

Okay I understand it now sorry. Do you know any kind of characterization of functions that have the property ?

I don't. Perhaps a 3-periodic point implies it.
